# OverlayView in MapLibre?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, mapbox-gl-js, maplibre-gl

I'm trying to replace Google Maps with MapLibre. What is the alternative of the OverlayView in MapLibre?

I've looked at all the examples of both MapLibre and Mapbox, but I couldn't find anything like what I currently have - an interactive (clickable items inside) overlay view that scales and moves with the map. All I got is a way to add a static image, but that looses my interactivity.

[image: Working Google Maps example]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to click events like this:

`map.on("myimagelayer", "click", e => (...))`